# How to dynamically create a type from an instance and modify some or access protected fields?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns

I need to mock and test some behavior on my domain entity. The domain entity has Id as the protected field. Some of the the behavior on my domain entity use that Id to figure out if the entity is a new or dirtied one. So how can I dynamically create a class that inherits from the  domain entity, so that I have access to the protected field. Similar to the proxies that entity framework creates. Or If there is any other better way to mock and still test the functions on the domain class. Please see example code below:

```
public class Customer{
  public Id {get; protected set;}
  public bool SomeMethod(){
    //This method check if the Id == 0 then it's a new instance and if not then 
    //Old instance
  }
}

public void Test_SomeMethod(){
  var customer = Customer.GetInstance();
  //Test the Somemethod. By mocking that it's not a new instance
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.nuget.org/packages/rhinomocks) maybe could help.

Comment: We are using Moq as mocking framework. Looks like Moq supports that too. Thanks for the answer @Alesssandro

Answer (score 2):

You can always use *Castle DynamicProxy* project in order to create runtime proxies:

- http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=DynamicProxy&NS=Tools&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Well in fact, check this statement from their wiki:

> Moq and Rhino Mocks both use it to provide their mocking
>   capabilities.

Why don't you take a look at these mocking frameworks (Moq and Rhino Mocks)?

Comment: Thanks @Matias. We are using Moq in the unit tests. Just that I didn't know it has the dynamic proxy capability

Comment: @BrikeshKumar That's why this site is great: continuous learning!!